# failed to replace column values in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, dataframe

I have the dataframe like:

```
              date_time       ID    Direction
  0 2015-05-22 05:37:59       10.0   
  1 2015-05-22 05:37:59       10.0    TRUE
  2 2015-05-22 05:37:59       10.0     
  3 2015-05-26 05:56:59       9.0     
  4 2015-05-26 05:56:59       9.0     TRUE
  5 2015-05-26 05:56:59       10.0    TRUE
 ......................    ......  ......
```

And I try to decode the values of column `Direction`, replacing `TRUE` by `right` if corresponding `ID` is 9.0 and `left` if it's 10.0

I'm trying the following code:

```
def directions():
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        if row['ID']=='9.0':
            row['Direction'] = row['Direction'].map({'TRUE': 'right', '': ''})
        elif row['ID']=='10.0':
            row['Direction'] = row['Direction'].map({'TRUE': 'left', '': ''})
    return df
```

it throws no error,but it doesn't change anything in existing dataframe, have you idea where can be a problem? 
I thought about using `iloc` `loc` but I'm not very strong with this methods, so if you know how better apply them to this case, it could be solution for my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is that the iterator returns a copy of the rows, and modifying the copy will not modify the original data. You can use the `loc` property to modify a view of the data like this:

```
def directions(df):
    df.loc[(df['ID'] == 9) & (df['Direction'] == 'TRUE'), 'Direction'] = 'right'
    df.loc[(df['ID'] == 10) & (df['Direction'] == 'TRUE'), 'Direction'] = 'left'
    return df
```

---

Edit – some explanation of `loc`:

You can think of `loc` as just a way to index rows and columns of dataframes in a flexible way. The syntax is `df.loc[row_indicator, col_indicator]`. The row/col indicator is very flexible: it can be a boolean mask, an index, a slice, a list of indices, etc. It's very similar to the various indexing schemes available in NumPy.

Let's look in detail at what this solution does. We first construct a boolean mask which indicates where the ID is 9:

```
>>> mask_ID9 = (df['ID'] == 9)
>>> mask_ID9
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
4     True
5    False
Name: ID, dtype: bool
```

We can use this mask to index the dataframe, and access all rows where the mask is True:

```
>>> df.loc[mask_ID9]
             date_time  ID Direction
3  2015-05-26-05:56:59   9        ''
4  2015-05-26-05:56:59   9     right
```

But we further want to limit this to the columns where the Direction is TRUE:

```
>>> mask_TRUE = (df['Direction'] == 'TRUE')
>>> mask_TRUE
0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
4     True
5     True
Name: Direction, dtype: bool
```

We can now combine these with the logical AND operator to find where both conditions are True:

```
>>> mask_ID9 & mask_TRUE
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
5    False
dtype: bool
```

Indexing with this will return just row 4, because it's the only one where these conditions are met:

```
>>> df.loc[mask_ID9 & mask_TRUE]
             date_time  ID Direction
4  2015-05-26-05:56:59   9     right
```

But we don't want the *whole* row, we just want the `'Direction'` column, so we add this to the `loc` call:

```
>>> df.loc[mask_ID9 & mask_TRUE, 'Direction']
4    TRUE
Name: Direction, dtype: object
```

Now we can just assign the appropriate value to this part of the DataFrame:

```
>>> df.loc[mask_ID9 & mask_TRUE, 'Direction'] = 'right'
>>> df
             date_time  ID Direction
0  2015-05-22-05:37:59  10        ''
1  2015-05-22-05:37:59  10      TRUE
2  2015-05-22-05:37:59  10        ''
3  2015-05-26-05:56:59   9        ''
4  2015-05-26-05:56:59   9     right
5  2015-05-26-05:56:59  10      TRUE
```

Changing the `left` value works similarly.

Comment: Thank you! as I supposed the ```loc``` is a solution for my problem, but could you explain, please, how it happens that it replaces only non-empty cells of ```Direction``` column (what I needed indeed) and not all the rows that correspond to  ```df['ID'] == 10``` (what I was afraid of)

Comment: ow, you posted the edited answer, but even the previous version worked the same way!! :)

Comment: I added some more info on how ``loc`` works here. Hope it helps!

Comment: thank you @jakevdp ! it's very clear explanation, but what was strange for me for instance - that this assignment ```df.loc[(df['ID'] == 9.0) & (df['Direction']), 'Direction'] = 'right' ``` works the same way that ```df.loc[(df['ID'] == 9) & (df['Direction'] == 'TRUE'), 'Direction'] = 'right'``` , even if in first case we don't explicitly access the rows where ```Direction``` is True

Comment: The reason the other way works is because the strings are converted to boolean directly: in the standard Python manner, nonempty strings are treated as ``True``, and empty strings are treated as ``False``. Check out the output of e.g. ``pd.Series(['ABC', '', 'TRUE', '']).astype(bool)`` to see this in action.